# Jenkins plugin installed failed with error some plugins could not be loaded due to unsatisfied dependencies?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

**Dependency errors**

-Pipeline Graph Analysis Plugin (1.10)
 Plugin is missing: pipeline-input-step (2.8)

-Jenkins Git client plugin (3.2.1)
 Plugin is missing: apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api (4.5.10-2.0)

-Pipeline: Basic Steps (2.19)
 Plugin is missing: apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api (4.5.5-3.0)

Some of the above failures also result in additional indirectly dependent plugins not being able to load.

**Indirectly dependent plugins**

-GitHub plugin (1.29.5)
 Failed to load: Jenkins Git plugin (4.2.2)

-Pipeline (2.6)
 Failed to load: Pipeline: Stage View Plugin (2.13)

-Pipeline: Stage View Plugin (2.13)
 Failed to load: Pipeline: REST API Plugin (2.13)

-Pipeline: Declarative (1.6.0)
 Failed to load: Pipeline: Basic Steps (2.19)

-Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries (2.16)
 Failed to load: Jenkins GIT server Plugin (1.9)

-GitHub Branch Source Plugin (2.6.0)
 Failed to load: GitHub plugin (1.29.5)

-Pipeline: GitHub Groovy Libraries (1.0)
 Failed to load: Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries (2.16)

-Gradle Plugin (1.36)
 Failed to load: Pipeline: Basic Steps (2.19)

-Docker Pipeline (1.23)
 Failed to load: Pipeline: Basic Steps (2.19)

-Pipeline: REST API Plugin (2.13)
 Failed to load: Pipeline Graph Analysis Plugin (1.10)

-Git plugin (4.2.2)
 Failed to load: Jenkins Git client plugin (3.2.1)

-GIT server Plugin (1.9)
 Failed to load: Jenkins Git client plugin (3.2.1)

Comment: Make sure Jenkins itself is up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

Go to jenkins > manage jenkins > manage plugins > available(tab) >
tick on --->>> GitHub plugin,gradle,Pipeline Graph Analysis Plugin , Pipeline: Stage View Plugin ,pipeline,Pipeline: REST API Plugin,Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries ,GitHub Branch Source Plugin ,Pipeline: GitHub Groovy Libraries ,Docker Pipeline ,Pipeline: REST API Plugin,Git plugin ,GIT server Plugin .

> install without restart

> after completing all installation successfully -> go to url(localhost:8080/restart) {Note: slash(/)restart is very important, type it manually after localhost:8080}

> Are you sure you want to restart Jenkins? ---->>> click on "YES" button

I hope your problem will be solve :)